# How can I repeat my Code in Windows Mousehook while mouse1 is held down

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to repeat my function in my mousehook while the left mouse button is held down. But with my current code, it only gets called once. I assumed that when I hold down the left mouse button the code gets called over and over again and I am not sure if this actually works what I wanna try. I need the code to run in the hook for timing purposes.

```
LRESULT __stdcall hk_mouse( int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        switch (wParam) {
            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            {
                Beep( 1000, 100 );
                break;
            }
            case WM_LBUTTONUP:
            {
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx( mouse_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam );
}
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to do while the button is down, but you can set a flag when you receive `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` then unset it when you receive `WM_LBUTTONUP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouse button messages don't repeat in Windows.

When you receive `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` you should [create a timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer) with the repeat delay you require, and then handle `WM_TIMER` messages in your hook proc and look for the timer ID you specified when creating the timer.

When the mouse button is released and you receive `WM_LBUTTONUP` you should [delete the timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-killtimer).

You should note that any code you execute in response to the `WM_TIMER` message should also be executed in the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` event (unless you want a delay when the button is first pressed), so it would be best to put that code in a function that can then be called from both places.